# Create a temp table show percentage of null value for all column in a given table

Tags: sql-server, loops, cursor, execute

I have an sql server loop exercise : Write code to create a table that shows percentage of null/ blank value for all the columns of table sql_practice . ( sql_practice table of my database have many columns so I need to use loop but I dont know how to code)

Comment: You can....but looping would be silly here. Perhaps you can explain what you are trying to do more clearly? A [mcve] would help considerably.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish but something like this will give you the percentage of rows for a single column that is not null. You could extend this to additional columns easily.

```
declare @Something table
(
    MyCol int null
)

insert @Something values
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(null),(null)

select NotNullPercentage = count(MyCol) / (count(*) * 1.0) --need to multiply by 1.0 to avoid integer math
from @Something
```